Costmap boundaries
Is there a way I can manipulate a costmap so that the outermost cells of the inflated obstacles in the x axis are counted as the map borders. I think I can write a script that does that using Python or C++ but I don't know how to publish that as data that is usable by ROS or any pathfinding algortihm. It would be so much easier if there is a package that handles creating dynamic boundaries.
I tried to illusturate what I mean below;

